# Resolving Silverlight GridSplitter Window Minimizing Bug

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml, gridsplitter

There is a small bug that we observed with the Silverlight GridSplitter.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="GreenYellow"/>
    <sdk:GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="AntiqueWhite"/>
</Grid>
```

Let me describe the workflow to reproduce this bug. 
 1. Drag the splitter up/down and with the mouse pressed over it (do not release the mouse).
 2. Press (Windows Logo Key + M) on the keyboard in order to minimize the browser.
 3. Release the mouse now.
 4. Switch back to the browser and observe that the GridSplitter is now located at the bottom of the Screen in the browser. And also it doesn't work as expected anymore.

Is there any method to fix this behavior and a reason for such a strange behavior of the GridSplitter. I understand that there won't be any future releases for Silverlight. How can we fix this bug? Is it possible through some kind of a behavior?

Comment: The answer is not to do that? Who does hold click and type anyway. You cant use both hands. However you could try to call InvalidateMeasure() or InvalidateVisual() or InvalidateProperty() methods after mouse was released. That might cause the Grid to remeasure, redraw...

Comment: Here's what I think happens. The top and bottom rows have the height * so while you switch back to the browser it must be trying to render  them and only be able to allocate * (all available) height to the top row and then 5px to the grid splitter and none to the bottom row. Hence the grid splitter appears at the bottom and since the bottom row has no allocated height , the splitter appears to be non functional.

Could you try giving the top row and bottom row the heights "8*" and "2*" to verify it..?

Comment: Works on my project - The grid splitter stays where it was when Win + M was pressed, it just still acts as though it is pressed when the window is maximized again.

Comment: @DNKROZ exactly, I also observe the same behavior. On restoring the minimized window, when we hover the mouse over the GridSplitter, we get the handle without even pressing it again, which is kind of strange. Any idea how I can resolve this issue? :(

I tried handling KeyUp or KeyDown and in that handler, I am explicitly calling ReleaseMouseCapture() method but still when i restore the browser and hover over the GridSplitter, I see that it considers the mouse to be in pressed state and we can simply move the mouse up and down (without pressing) to resize

Comment: @devhedgehog calling the InvalidateMeasure() fixes the issue of the GridSplitter going to the bottom of the screen but it still has the problem of considering the mouse to be pressed and can be dragged freely without actually pressing, just on hover as explained above.

Comment: You could change the clickmode or pressmode.

Comment: @devhedgehog I didn't find such property on GridSplitter :(